# How do I store TimePicker Data in my simple record keeping app?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, timepicker

I've created a simple record keeping application using various resources around the internet. I'm able to successfully store text data - however when I attempt to incorporate a TimePicker I end up crashing my entire app.

Any input on how this can be implemented (as well as any code examples) are greatly appreciated!

**DATA INPUT XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1">

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical" 
  android:padding="5dp">

  <EditText android:id="@+id/nameEdit"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:imeOptions="actionNext" 
     android:hint="@string/name_hint"
     android:inputType="textPersonName|textCapWords"/>

  <EditText android:id="@+id/capEdit"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:imeOptions="actionNext" 
     android:hint="@string/cap_hint"
     android:inputType="textPersonName|textCapWords"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Data Limit"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="10MB" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="Unlimited Data" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Bandwidth Limit"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="10kbs" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="Unlimited Bandwidth" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="WiFi Time Limit"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />

<TimePicker
    android:id="@+id/timePicker1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1.0" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/codeEdit"
    android:inputType="textUri"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:lines="1"
    android:hint="@string/code_hint"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext" />




  <Button android:id="@+id/saveBtn" 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
     android:text="@string/save_btn"/>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**DATA INPUT JAVA:**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class AddEditCountry extends Activity {

 private long rowID; 
 private EditText nameEt;
 private EditText capEt;
 private EditText codeEt;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
      setContentView(R.layout.add_country);

      nameEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameEdit);
      capEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.capEdit);
      codeEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.codeEdit);

      Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 

      if (extras != null)
      {
         rowID = extras.getLong("row_id");
         nameEt.setText(extras.getString("name"));  
         capEt.setText(extras.getString("cap"));  
         codeEt.setText(extras.getString("code"));  
      }

      Button saveButton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);
      saveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          public void onClick(View v) 
          {
             if (nameEt.getText().length() != 0)
             {
                AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> saveContactTask = 
                   new AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>() 
                   {
                      @Override
                      protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) 
                      {
                         saveContact();
                         return null;
                      }

                      @Override
                      protected void onPostExecute(Object result) 
                      {
                         finish();
                      }
                   }; 

                saveContactTask.execute((Object[]) null); 
             }

             else
             {
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new  AlertDialog.Builder(AddEditCountry.this);
                alert.setTitle(R.string.errorTitle); 
                alert.setMessage(R.string.errorMessage);
                alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.errorButton, null); 
                alert.show();
             }
          } 
     });
   }

   private void saveContact() 
   {
      DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(this);

      if (getIntent().getExtras() == null)
      {
          dbConnector.insertContact(nameEt.getText().toString(),
                  capEt.getText().toString(),
                  codeEt.getText().toString());
      }
      else
      {
         dbConnector.updateContact(rowID,
            nameEt.getText().toString(),
            capEt.getText().toString(), 
            codeEt.getText().toString());
      }
   }
}
```

DATA OUTPUT XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:stretchColumns="1" 
  android:layout_margin="5dp">

   <TableRow>         
     <TextView 
        style="@style/StyleLabel"
        android:text="@string/name_lbl"/>
     <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/nameText" 
        style="@style/StyleText"/>         
  </TableRow>

  <TableRow>         
     <TextView 
        style="@style/StyleLabel"
        android:text="@string/cap_lbl"/>         
     <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/capText"
        style="@style/StyleText"/>         
  </TableRow>

  <TableRow>         
     <TextView 
        style="@style/StyleLabel"
        android:text="@string/code_lbl"/>         
     <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/codeText"
        style="@style/StyleText"/>         
  </TableRow>
  <TableRow>         
     <TextView 
        style="@style/StyleLabel"
        android:text="Linked Users"/>         
     <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/codeText"
        style="@style/StyleText"/>         
  </TableRow>
   <TableRow>         
     <TextView 
        style="@style/StyleLabel"
        android:text="Time Limit"/>         
     <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/timeText"
        style="@style/StyleText"/>         
  </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

**DATA OUTPUT JAVA:**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ViewCountry extends Activity {

   private long rowID;
   private TextView nameTv;
   private TextView capTv;
   private TextView codeTv; 

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.view_country);

      setUpViews();
      Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
      rowID = extras.getLong(CountryList.ROW_ID); 
   }

   private void setUpViews() {
       nameTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameText);
       capTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.capText);
       codeTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.codeText);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onResume()
   {
      super.onResume();
      new LoadContacts().execute(rowID);
   } 

   private class LoadContacts extends AsyncTask<Long, Object, Cursor> 
   {
      DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(ViewCountry.this);

      @Override
      protected Cursor doInBackground(Long... params)
      {
         dbConnector.open();
         return dbConnector.getOneContact(params[0]);
      } 

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result)
      {
         super.onPostExecute(result);

         result.moveToFirst();
         // get the column index for each data item
         int nameIndex = result.getColumnIndex("name");
         int capIndex = result.getColumnIndex("cap");
         int codeIndex = result.getColumnIndex("code");

         nameTv.setText(result.getString(nameIndex));
         capTv.setText(result.getString(capIndex));
         codeTv.setText(result.getString(codeIndex));

         result.close();
         dbConnector.close();
      }
   } 


   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
   {
      super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
      MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
      inflater.inflate(R.menu.view_country_menu, menu);
      return true;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
   {
      switch (item.getItemId())
      {
         case R.id.editItem:
            Intent addEditContact =
               new Intent(this, AddEditCountry.class);

            addEditContact.putExtra(CountryList.ROW_ID, rowID);
            addEditContact.putExtra("name", nameTv.getText());
            addEditContact.putExtra("cap", capTv.getText());
            addEditContact.putExtra("code", codeTv.getText());
            startActivity(addEditContact); 
            return true;

         case R.id.deleteItem:
            deleteContact();
            return true;

         default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
      } 
   }

   private void deleteContact()
   {

      AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(ViewCountry.this);

      alert.setTitle(R.string.confirmTitle); 
      alert.setMessage(R.string.confirmMessage); 

      alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.delete_btn,
         new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
         {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int button)
            {
               final DatabaseConnector dbConnector = 
                  new DatabaseConnector(ViewCountry.this);

               AsyncTask<Long, Object, Object> deleteTask =
                  new AsyncTask<Long, Object, Object>()
                  {
                     @Override
                     protected Object doInBackground(Long... params)
                     {
                        dbConnector.deleteContact(params[0]); 
                        return null;
                     } 

                     @Override
                     protected void onPostExecute(Object result)
                     {
                        finish(); 
                     }
                  };

               deleteTask.execute(new Long[] { rowID });               
            }
         }
      );

      alert.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel_btn, null).show();
   }
}
```

**DATABASE CONNECTOR JAVA:**

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;


public class DatabaseConnector {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "WorldCountries";
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private DatabaseOpenHelper dbOpenHelper;

    public DatabaseConnector(Context context) {
        dbOpenHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    public void open() throws SQLException 
    {
        //open database in reading/writing mode
        database = dbOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    } 

    public void close() 
    {
        if (database != null)
        database.close();
    }      

    public void insertContact(String name, String cap, String code) {
        ContentValues newCon = new ContentValues();
        newCon.put("name", name);
        newCon.put("cap", cap);
        newCon.put("code", code);

        open();
        database.insert("country", null, newCon);
        close();
    }


    public void updateContact(long id, String name, String cap,String code) 
    {
        ContentValues editCon = new ContentValues();
        editCon.put("name", name);
        editCon.put("cap", cap);
        editCon.put("code", code);

        pen();
        database.update("country", editCon, "_id=" + id, null);
        close();
    }


    public Cursor getAllContacts() 
    {
        return database.query("country", new String[] {"_id",  "name"}, 
             null, null, null, null, "name");
    }

    public Cursor getOneContact(long id) 
    {
        return database.query("country", null, "_id=" + id, null, null, null, null);
    }

    public void deleteContact(long id) 
    {
        open(); 
        database.delete("country", "_id=" + id, null);
        close();
    }
}
```

**DATABASE HELPER JAVA:**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context context, String name,
            CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String createQuery = "CREATE TABLE country (_id integer primary key autoincrement,name, cap, code);";                 
        db.execSQL(createQuery);        
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

in you create table statement define a type

```
CREATE TABLE ...... dtField date, tmpName Text.....
```

use following for saving date as text

```
//sample date format - 2013-03-21 13:12:00
android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", dtDate.getTime())
```